# What is the purpose of a manifest.txt file in a Java web app?

Tags: java, configuration

What is the purpose of a manifest.txt file? I'm working with a CMS that says that in order for me to create database objects, I have to create this `manifest.txt` file with the path to each script that I need to run in the exact order they must be run.

Comment: Maybe you want to check the documentation of your CMS.

Comment: @Chiron There's absolutely no documentation on it. The documentation just says to create a manifest.txt file to do "stuff" (it's a wiki type documentation). This is exactly what it says...."Each directory containing raw SQL objects (view definitions, pre- and post-update scripts, etc.) must include a manifest.txt file to specify object creation or script execution order in order to ensure compilation dependencies are met. The manifest is simply a list of newline-separated script names (without the database-specific suffix)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manifest files generally contain metadata for modules/components etc. Their exact purpose and format is dependent on the system they are for. In your case it will be your CMS. Have a look at the CMS documentation for information of how it is to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the general idea. Like I said to @chiron it's not documented very well, but it's what I have to work with. Thank you.